# Questions about real time audio signal processing with PyAudio and PyQtGraph

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, pyaudio, pyqtgraph

I need to do some real time audio signal processing with Python, i.e. analyze the signal in the frequency domain by framing, windowing and computing the FFT, and then apply some filters depending on the analysis results. I've been using PyAudio for audio acquisition and PyQtGraph for waveform and FFT visualization, as suggested in [this](https://github.com/mfarhan12/pycon-canada-2015/blob/master/scripts/PyAudio/pyaudio_example.py) and [this code](https://gist.github.com/boylea/1a0b5442171f9afbf372).

For now my code only detects the `N` power spectrum bins with the highest value and highlights them by drawing vertical lines on the FFT plot. Here is what is looks like :

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore


##Some settings

FORMAT = pyaudio.paFloat32
CHANNELS = 1
FS = 44100
CHUNK = 256
NFFT = 2048
OVERLAP = 0.5
PLOTSIZE = 32*CHUNK
N = 4

freq_range = np.linspace(10, FS/2, NFFT//2 + 1)
df = FS/NFFT
HOP = NFFT*(1-OVERLAP)


##Some preliminary functions

def db_spectrum(data) : #computes positive frequency power spectrum
    fft_input = data*np.hanning(NFFT)
    spectrum = abs(np.fft.rfft(fft_input))/NFFT
    spectrum[1:-1] *= 2
    return 20*np.log10(spectrum)

def highest_peaks(spectrum) : #finds peaks (local maxima) and picks the N highest ones
    peak_indices = argrelextrema(spectrum, np.greater)[0]
    peak_values = spectrum[peak_indices]
    highest_peak_indices = np.argpartition(peak_values, -N)[-N:]
    return peak_indices[(highest_peak_indices)]

def detection_plot(peaks) : #formats data for vertical line plotting
    x = []
    y = []
    for peak in peaks :
        x.append(peak*df)
        x.append(peak*df)
        y.append(-200)
        y.append(0)
    return x, y


##Main class containing loop and UI

class SpectrumAnalyzer(pg.GraphicsWindow) :

    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__() 
        self.initUI()
        self.initTimer()
        self.initData()
        self.pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.pa.open(format = FORMAT,
                                   channels = CHANNELS,
                                   rate = FS,
                                   input = True,
                                   output = True,
                                   frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)

    def initUI(self) :
        self.setWindowTitle("Microphone Audio Data")
        audio_plot = self.addPlot(title="Waveform")
        audio_plot.showGrid(True, True)
        audio_plot.addLegend()
        audio_plot.setYRange(-1,1)
        self.time_curve = audio_plot.plot()
        self.nextRow()
        fft_plot = self.addPlot(title="FFT") 
        fft_plot.showGrid(True, True)
        fft_plot.addLegend()
        fft_plot.setLogMode(True, False)
        fft_plot.setYRange(-140,0) #may be adjusted depending on your input
        self.fft_curve = fft_plot.plot(pen='y')
        self.detection = fft_plot.plot(pen='r')

    def initTimer(self) :
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(0)

    def initData(self) :
        self.waveform_data = np.zeros(PLOTSIZE)
        self.fft_data = np.zeros(NFFT)
        self.fft_counter = 0

    def closeEvent(self, event) :
        self.timer.stop()
        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.stream.close()
        self.pa.terminate()

    def update(self) :

        raw_data = self.stream.read(CHUNK)
        self.stream.write(raw_data, CHUNK)
        self.fft_counter += CHUNK

        sample_data = np.fromstring(raw_data, dtype=np.float32)
        self.waveform_data = np.concatenate([self.waveform_data, sample_data])  #update plot data
        self.waveform_data = self.waveform_data[CHUNK:]                         #
        self.time_curve.setData(self.waveform_data)

        self.fft_data = np.concatenate([self.fft_data, sample_data])    #update fft input
        self.fft_data = self.fft_data[CHUNK:]                           #
        if self.fft_counter == HOP :
            spectrum = db_spectrum(self.fft_data)
            peaks = highest_peaks(spectrum)
            x, y = detection_plot(peaks)
            self.detection.setData(x, y, connect = 'pairs')
            self.fft_curve.setData(freq_range, spectrum)
            self.fft_counter = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spec = SpectrumAnalyzer()
```

The code works fine but I still have some questions :

- I understand that by calling `timer.start()` with `0` as an argument, the `update` method is being called again as soon as possible. How does my script know that the `update` method needs be called only when the next audio chunk is received and not before ?
- In the codes I linked above, the `closeEvent` method is not modified in order to stop the timer and the stream when closing the PyQtGraph window. What used to happen for me is that even after closing the window, the `update` method was being called and my audio recorded. Was that normal behavior ?
- I've read that when using PyQt GUIs, I should always start by calling a `QtGui.QApplication` instance and call the `exec` method. Why is that and why is my code working even though I'm not doing it ?
- In the future I will need to implement analysis that is much more demanding than just detecting the `N` highest peaks. Given the actual structure of my code, if I add such analysis in the `update` method, I understand that the CPU will have to compute everything before the next audio chunk is received, while it could wait for the next FFT input data to be ready. The hop size being larger than the chunk size, this will give the CPU more time to compute everything. How can I achieve this ? Multi-threading ?